# Не получается подключить библиотеку в CodeBlocks C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Создал библиотеку в CodeBlocks, создал новый проект, хотел подключить библиотеку, но ошибка -  No such file or directory , в настройки проекта добавил библиотеку, но все равно не работает.

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drBEM.jpg)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ¿Вы же осознаете различие между статической библиотекой (.a) и заголовочным файлом (.h)?

Comment: В search directories -> compiler указать папку, где лежит этот `.h`.